# Googlemap and latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I'm stucked with lat and long :|

What I do: I'm using LocationManager for getting my current position (I made dialog... which show me loading screen while loading

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
```

but.. im set a log.. or just a simple message.. I never get request from this function.

But if I'm using googlemap fragment .. there I press on button in right side at top and it's instantly showin my current location.. How to be correct in this situation? how to get cur location (lat and long)?

I'm just stucked :(

```
public class getLocation implements LocationListener
    {
        public getLocation()
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading GPS Information");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.show();
            lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

             boolean enabled = lm
                      .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


                    if (!enabled) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS NOT ENABLED" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                      startActivity(intent);
                    } else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS  ENABLED" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LAST LOCATION " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Last location unknown ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                                0, getLocation.this);
                    }
                        }
                        });
                    }
                    }.start();

                     handler = new Handler() {
                            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            };
                        };
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub =
            if(loc!=null){
            if(apress){
                at.setText("Lat = "+loc.getLatitude()+" | Long = "+loc.getLongitude());
                apress=false;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnLocationChanged GPS" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                latG=loc.getLatitude();
                longG=loc.getLongitude();
                showA.setEnabled(true);
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnLocationChanged GPS Location - null" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ON PROVIDER DISABLED "+arg0 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ON PROVIDER ENABLED "+arg0 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ON STATUS CHANGED  "+arg0 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

and in this function

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
```

I never get correct call.. it's mean if I adding here Log.e( or something) than it's never show :(

Comment: Can you add your all class codes

Comment: hey peter!
if I understood your questions correctly. you need to remove "Show location button" from Fragment.
second thing you want know to your lat and long

Comment: @TarunSharma no , i want get cur LAT and LONG with code  not on map, im just cant understand why it's not working, BUT on map "Show location button " as u sayd - this button always showing me where i am :((((( i want it by code

Comment: do you get "0.0" from latitude and longitude?

Comment: @BatuhanC yea , always ... it's near africa o_O i think it' just a middle

Comment: It is because of the flag `apress` on your code. GPSProvider gives your location 0 at the beginning of your app. You should let your codes to check location more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this subclass;

```
private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener,
        GpsStatus.Listener {
    boolean isGPSFix;

    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            if (mLastLocation != null)
                isGPSFix = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastGPStime) < 3000;
            if (isGPSFix) { // A fix has been acquired.
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(GPSLocationService.this, "GPS has a fix.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            } else { // The fix has been lost.
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(GPSLocationService.this, "GPS DOES NOT have a fix.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(GPSLocationService.this, "GPS got first fix.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            isGPSFix = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(apress){
            try {
                latG = location.getLatitude();
                longG = location.getLongitude();
                at.setText("Lat = "+latG +" | Long = "+longG);
                apress=false;
                showA.setEnabled(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                latG = 0.0;
                longG = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        String statusDescription = "unknown";
        switch (status) {
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            statusDescription = "OUT_OF_SERVICE";
            break;
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            statusDescription = "AVAILABLE";
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            statusDescription = "TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE";
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(GPSLocationService.this, "Your GPS is opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(GPSLocationService.this, "Your GPS is closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Then call this class from your MainActivity with the codes;

```
GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
// get the system manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsLocationListener);
```

Do not forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` on your manifest.

Comment: for clean code. You set a thread on getLocation class constructor and in this thread you call getLocation class again with `lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, getLocation.this);`. So where did you first call getLocation class?

Answer (score 0):

Well ... code work correct.  Just need stay under sky for correct work..  i was at home . thats why im not getting coords(lat and long. thanks all ...